# Is there a valid way to use redux with react without react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn redux and implementing it in react without react-redux. Why you ask? just want to learn vanilla redux. so  I use this approach:

```
const render = () => ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

store.subscribe(render);

render();
```

Now the redux store listens for a dispatch and runs the render callback on every single change.
**The problem is that all the components in the app will be rendered when a change to the store occurs,because we subscribe the root element. I want only the the relevant components(the components that actually use the state in the store that changed) to be rendered.**
Is there a way to do it only with "redux" without "react-redux"?

thanks.

Comment: Check out `TheNetNinja` youtube channel. This guy is really knows ninja techniques to simplify anything you want to learn.

Comment: @Mrjadeja thanks, I've watched his react and redux series, he uses react-redux without explaining how to connect redux to react without react-redux.

Comment: Here's a quick video by Max, The one in his course on Udemy explained it (Redux Alone) a lot better, but this should help: https://youtu.be/ZKCYqJu4n3s

Comment: @comphonia the video doesn't answer my question, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Set up redux according to their docs, it sure does not rerender entire app on state change. Only affected components are re-rendered

Comment: @Max they use react-redux in the docs, I'm asking about using redux without react-redux.

Comment: you want to use it without react-redux to avoid "rerendering entire app" but react-redux doesn't re-render entire app in first place @morh

Comment: @Max No. I want to use it without react-redux in order to learn vanilla redux properly.

Comment: I see, my bad then @morh

Comment: This tutorial from the creator of Redux himself, Dan Abramov, teaches you vanilla redux in the context of no other frameworks/libraries. https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-store-methods-getstate-dispatch-and-subscribe

Comment: I think this article describes what the OP is asking for https://betterprogramming.pub/you-dont-even-need-react-redux-and-redux-thunk-d9dce6c0a89f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very naive way to implement react-redux yourself that may give you a better understanding what goes on but I'd advice not to do this in any real application you'd write, only for learning purposes:

```js
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = { counter: 0 };
//action types
const ADD = 'ADD';
//action creators
const add = (howMuch) => ({
  type: ADD,
  payload: howMuch,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD) {
    return { ...state, counter: state.counter + payload };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectCounter = (state) => state.counter;
//creating store with redux dev tools
//assuming only one store is used, useSelector and useDispatch
//  are based on this store
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
//useDispatch will just return store.dispatch function
const useDispatch = () => store.dispatch;
//custom hook checking if component is still mounted
//  you should not set state if component is unmounted
const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => (isMounted.current = false);
  }, []);
  return isMounted;
};
//default compare function
const refCompare = (a, b) => a === b;
//useSelector will listen to store changes and set local state
//  if it changed
const useSelector = (selectFn, compareFn = refCompare) => {
  //set local state with the result from the selector
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(() =>
    selectFn(store.getState())
  );
  //to prevent setting state on unmounted component
  const mounted = useIsMounted();
  //effect to listen to store changes
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //listen to store changes and unsubscribe when unmount
    //  or functions change
    const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      //run the selector
      const currentStoreState = selectFn(store.getState());
      //do not set state when component is unmounted
      if (!mounted.current) return;
      //call setState with callback when returning a different
      //  value the component should re render although it also
      //  re render sometimes when same value is returned
      //  I am not sure why this is but happens when pressing
      //  add count and then unrelated action
      //  bug reported here:
      //  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20817
      setState(
        (currentLocalState) =>
          //see if result of the selector changed
          compareFn(currentLocalState, currentStoreState)
            ? currentLocalState //do nothing, state didn't change
            : currentStoreState //state did change, assign it to local state
      );
    });
    //unsubscribe when unmounted or functions passed changed
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [compareFn, mounted, selectFn]);
  return state;
};
//Counter will re render when selectCounter(reduxState)
//  changes but will also sometimes render when it doesn't
//  not sure why but should not according to documentation
//  of setState
const Counter = React.memo(function Counter() {
  const counter = useSelector(selectCounter);
  console.log('rendering counter with', counter);
  return <div>{counter}</div>;
});
//should render only when state changes from odd to even
const OddEven = React.memo(function OddEven() {
  //should only render when isOdd changes but will render
  //  one extra time after a change and first time it
  //  doesn't change, not according to how setState should
  //  work and would be grateful if someone can explain
  //  why this happens as it's not according to setState
  //  documentation
  const isOdd = useSelector((state) =>
    Boolean(selectCounter(state) % 2)
  );
  console.log('rendering OddEven', isOdd);
  return <div>{isOdd ? 'odd' : 'even'}</div>;
});
//in this implementation no provider is needed because it doesn't
//  use React.context
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log('in App render');
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch({ type: 'unrelated action' })
        }
      >
        dispatch unrelated action (no re renders)
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(add(1))}>
        add 1
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(add(2))}>
        add 2
      </button>
      <Counter />
      <OddEven />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is your render example, it doesn't work at all with pure components because it'll only render `<App />` and all components in App are pure components meaning they would only re render if props passed to it would change.

```js
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = { counter: 0 };
//action types
const ADD = 'ADD';
//action creators
const add = (howMuch) => ({
  type: ADD,
  payload: howMuch,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  console.log('action:',type);
  if (type === ADD) {
    return { ...state, counter: state.counter + payload };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectCounter = (state) => state.counter;
//creating store with redux dev tools
//assuming only one store is used, useSelector and useDispatch
//  are based on this store
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const Counter = React.memo(function Counter() {
  const counter = selectCounter(store.getState());
  console.log('rendering counter with', counter);
  return <div>{counter}</div>;
});
const OddEven = React.memo(function OddEven() {
  const isOdd = Boolean(
    selectCounter(store.getState()) % 2
  );
  console.log('rendering OddEven', isOdd);
  return <div>{isOdd ? 'odd' : 'even'}</div>;
});
const App = () => {
  console.log('in app render');
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          store.dispatch({ type: 'unrelated action' })
        }
      >
        dispatch unrelated action (no re renders)
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => store.dispatch(add(1))}>
        add 1
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => store.dispatch(add(2))}>
        add 2
      </button>
      <Counter />
      <OddEven />
    </div>
  );
};

const render = () =>
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great!! exactly what i was looking for. last question. in the approach of subscribing the root element like I did, React.render() uses an algorithm and renders only if there is a change, so it doesn't matter how many times we call it(on store state change). but even then, all the components are re-rendered. what is the reason for it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4AHnEH8S the console.log("heyy from app") in the app component is called on every click. but the state is used only in the Game component.

Comment: @morh I added another snippet with your render solution but that doesn't work because it'll only create jsx for `<App />`, the children of app are pure components and will only re render when props passed to it change or local state changes. As for render being optimized, that means that when jsx is created react will compare current jsx with last jsx and only re render DOM where the jsx changed but as mentioned before; the children of App are pure and won't re render unless they also listen to redux store changes like I did in the first example.

Comment: @morh It is not a good idea to needlessly re create jsx (have components listen to store directly and re render even if they don't need to) because even if all the values are the same it needlessly re creates jsx for React to compare and when you have an event handler like `onClick={()=>new function every render}` then the virtual dom compare (jsx compare) will fail and React will needlessly re  render DOM. This can severely negatively impact performance.

Comment: My render solution is actually re-renders the Game component when clicking on the "shuffle" button, but it also re-renders the App component(I know it because i can see the output of console.log in the useEffect on every click), this is the problem. btw i have edited the pastebin because it was missing the subscription.

Comment: @morh Your pastebin re creates all jsx because none of the components are pure and functional components will re create jsx every time the parent re creates jsx, try using React.memo and see if it still works (definitely not as shown in my second snippet). I think your render should be `const render = () => ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));` as it currently will just throw an error

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use redux without react-redux, the only thing you should keep in mind is that you have to do some additional activities to achieve the same result. Here I give you a detailed example: https://www.stuffthatstough.com/archive/Redux%20React%20without%20React%20Redux
2. React redux is a UI binding library. This means that it contains all the helper methods that allow you actions like making it possible to update your UI and dispatch methods with ease. For example, react-redux's connect method allows mapping your store data/your actions to react props, making it easier to bind your UI components to redux. Without this connection, you would have to subscribe to a particular value in the store with a listener, and then calling a `setState` in the listener to react to the changes. When the number of listeners you need in a specific component increases, the code can become messy. In react-redux, however, by mapping state to props, all this data comes from props automatically, making it easier for you to manage them

Here you can find additional info: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/why-use-react-redux

Comment: Hey, your example in the link uses the same approach of subscribing the whole react app. this way all the components will render when a change to the state occurs. My question was how you avoid rendering the whole app and just render the relevant components...

Comment: Clarify your question. In the text was just requested if it was possible to use redux without using the react-redux library. Furthermore, if you need your data to be used just in one single place, redux can be "overkill". It is totally fine to use the local state of components to manage data related only to a single portion of the application. On the other side redux is useful when you need to share state across multiple components in an efficient way

Comment: "The problem is that all the components in the app will be rendered when a change to the store occurs, but I want only the the relevant components to be rendered. " . in the approach of subscribing the root element all the components are rendered on any store change, this is a real problem.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better. the approach you use it to call store.subscribe() on the root element of the app. this way we render the whole app again and again on any store change. this is the problem.

Comment: By the way, subscribe can be called anywhere in the app. The example above perform it at the root because, usually, redux is a way to store globally the state and make it accessible in the whole app. Usually, for the local state, we use hooks or react state. But nothing blocks you to subscribe single components to the store. Also with react-redux you can use the provider in a child component and not at the "render level". This is why I was telling that the problem here was not related to react-redux or redux, but was most related to where to subscribe to the store. Hope it helps